# YAIC (Yet Another Inheritance Confusion)

Tags: java

I am sure this type of question is asked every day, but I am struggling with understanding why the mammal object is instantiated as a cat, and reports its name to be Morris.  However, unlike most cats, it does not have 9 lives.  If the object is not a cat, why does it report its name to be Morris?

```
class Mammal  {
    int temp;
    String name = "George";

    public Mammal() {
        temp = 98;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Mammal {
    int lives;
    String name = "Morris";

    public Cat() {
        lives = 9;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Inheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mammal mm = new Cat();
        System.out.println("Mam Temp:" + mm.temp);
        //System.out.println("Cat Lives:" + mm.lives);        <-- error
        System.out.println("Mam Name:" + mm.getName());  
    }
}
```

Comment: You are viewing `Cat` as `Mammal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two related but concretely separate concepts here.

1. The runtime type of an object.
2. The static (and runtime) type of a variable.

The runtime type of the object will determine how it behaves at runtime.  It's determined by the constructor you called when you used the `new` keyword.

The static type of the variable dictates how your code can interact with or reference that variable (and the object it refers to).  It's determined by the type you specify when you *declare* that variable (or field, parameter, etc).

In this case, the static type of the variable is `Mammal` while the runtime type of the object it points to is `Cat`.  Thus, while it behaves like a `Cat` at runtime and shows its name as being 'Morris', at compile time the compiler only knows that it is a `Mammal`, and cannot refer to the `lives` variable (which is defined in `Cat`, not `Mammal`).

Comment: So it sounds like I am asking the wrong question (inheritance).  I am instead asking a casting question.

Answer (score 2):

Because the variable is of type `Mammal` which was set in the line `Mammal mm = new Cat();`. The `Mammal` class does not contain a variable `lives` and therefore it throws the error. If you do `((Cat)mm).lives` however, you should get the correct result because you are casting the `mm` variable to the type `Cat` (which it was initialized as).

**EDIT**

Also, you overrode the `getName()` Method in the `Cat` class which "hides" the one in the `Mammal` class. You created `mm` as a Type `Mammal` but in reality it's a `Cat` so a call to the `getName()` method on `mm` will call the child method `getName()` which returns `"Morris"` instead of `"George"`.

Comment: Overloaded or overridden?  I thought I overrode them method.

Comment: @BusterBunker You are correct, it was overridden that was my error. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You created an instance of `Cat` but you are treating it as a `Mammal`. `Mammal.lives` doesn't exist, which is why you get an error when you try to print `mm.lives`.

Incidentally, this is a good example of why inheritance can be dangerous and should be used sparingly. Cat and Mammal are tightly coupled by inheritance, so you have to understand both classes *and how they interact* in order to understand code that deals with `Cat`.

Answer (score 1):

the object created is that of Cat so the getName method when invoked is on the Cat object and hence its name is reported as "morris". The local variable however is defined as a Mammal so lives can not be accessed unless you explicitly cast it to a cat.